# Difference between "act according to" and "act under"

Tags: meaning, prepositions, difference

> “In particular, **acting under orders** caused participants to
>   perceive a distance from outcomes that they themselves caused,” said
>   study co-author Patrick Haggard, a cognitive neuroscientist at
>   University College London, in an email.”
>
> From
>   https://www.pbs.org/newshour/science/how-the-nazis-defense-of-just-following-orders-plays-out-in-the-mind

What is the difference between "act under"  and "act according to"? If I change "acting under orders" to "acting according to orders" here, would any nuance be lost?

I originally asked the same question here (https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/act-under-according-to-orders.3589389/#post-18265641), but sadly I didn't get a valid answer. I hope you can help me.

> Under: subject to the authority, control, guidance, or instruction of
>
> According to: In conformity with (Merriam Webster)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a fine distinction, and most of the time we'd see the two forms as synonymous, but I think the difference is implied by the two definitions as cited by OP.

Generally speaking, if you're *acting **under order[s]***, the implication is you've been given a *specific* order to do whatever it is.

If you *act **in accordance / accord** with orders*, or ***according to*** orders, this could often simply mean that the way you're doing something ***doesn't break the rules*** (i.e. - ***is legitimate***). You haven't necessarily been specifically instructed to do whatever it is.